# C++ dynamic dispatch without vtables

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, standards

As far as I know, C++ standard doesn't require the dynamic dispatch to be implemented using virtual method tables (a.k.a. vtables). Nevertheless, I have gotten the impression that vtables are the de facto standard implementation. I wonder whether there are C++ compilers that use a different mechanism or at least allow a different mechanism.

Comment: No, because a vtable is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Alex, efficient is subjective. I agree that probably vtable is the most balanced solution in a general case, but it isn't the fastest, so I can easily imagine a niche compiler that prefers a faster code but slower compilation and bigger image.

Comment: @FireAphis: On your average CPU, though, it's hard to imagine anything faster than some type of function table approach, which is how I think of a vtable.

Comment: Andrei Alexandrescu talked a bit about implementing your own inhertiance mechanism to optimize the function pointer lookup on certain architectures (it's still a vtable, just organized in a specific way): http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly  (you can skip to about 32 minutes into the talk)

Comment: Also, note that it's not a "lookup" in the expensive sense of the word. In the usual case, it's just indexing into a jump table.

Comment: @kec, agree. I was thinking mainly that probably there are architectures with "tricks" that allow a super efficient dynamic dispatch without vtables, googling it however gave me nothing.

Comment: It would be a lot of work for little benefit, though, to implement such a trick in hardware. By the way, I've benchmarked dynamic dispatch before. Even adding one conditional like this to a non-dynamic dispatch was slower than a virtual function call: `if (cond) a.non_virt1(); else a.non_virt2();`.

Comment: If you believe that "vtable... isn't the fastest", then you should propose an alternative, preferably in your question. One way to speed up calls is devirtualization, which is an optimization performed by most modern c++ compilers (and it's easy to google, hint, hint); I believe you get better results with clang and gcc if you enable LTO.

Comment: I can imagine that some niche or specialized *processors* might have mechanisms in place to speed-up dynamic dispatch, for example some [Java Processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor) that execute Java bytecode natively. But I don't know enough to say for sure.

Comment: @yzt The usual optimization, which is not at all niche, is branch prediction. Sure, you can also build the vtable fetching + calling into the CPU, but casting something in silicon [doesn't necessarily help](http://www.yosefk.com/blog/its-done-in-hardware-so-its-cheap.html). You'd save... two instruction dispatches. The pointer arithmetic still has to happen, the memory load won't get faster, the jump is still as much of a pipeline speed-bump, in that order. Dynamic code optimizations like inline caching are presumably beyond what can reasonably be done in hardware.

Comment: @delnan: I was thinking more along the lines of special caches that know their content is a vtable (i.e. a bunch of pointers to some functions.) I'm absolutely not a hardware person, but suppose you have a special instruction for (pre)loading the vtable, to which you provide the instance pointer and the index, and it would load the pointed-to function if it can. I do understand that "do it in hardware" is not a magic wand that you can wave and magically solve your problems, but I'm sure if you sacrifice some generality, you can get reasonable speedups in this case.

Comment: @yzt I don't really see how such a cache can add any meaningful optimizations. We already have general-purpose caches, they are already quite fast (L1 hit since cycle, L2 hit a few cycles), they work transparently for the code, are managed well, and multiple cores can cache the same stuff as long as it isn't modified. In fact, I suspect most vtable fetches always hit the cache. The only thing you'd gain is the ability to drop arbitrary data caches (to use less silicon and power) while still caching vtables, but caches are so universally useful that you'd want them anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard places few constraints on the implementation of virtual functions and the calling mechanism. Since it does however list a lot of things that cannot be virtual, that in effect adds to the freedom.

From n3797 10.3/1:

> Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented programming.

Then lots of stuff about what constitutes `overriding` and `final overrider`.

From 5.2.2/1:

> Otherwise [function is virtual], its final overrider (10.3) in the dynamic type of the object expression is called; such a call is referred to as a virtual function call. [ Note: the dynamic type is the type of the object referred to by the current value of the object expression...]

So the C++ standard defines a restricted kind of dynamic dispatch based on the dynamic type of the object, and nothing much else. As long as each object carries around a mechanism by which any virtual function can be called, everything else is up for grabs.

Yes, vtables are common but they are not the last word. They are a significant memory and speed cost, particularly for multiple inheritance. I can easily come up with a mechanism that is not a vtable but is just as fast and uses less object memory, but takes more space in code or static memory. Various researchers have devised a wealth of techniques, and some have even been patented. There are techniques that provide better type safety, or better branch prediction or even faster lookup. I don't see much point providing links -- you can easily find them too.

But no, I am not aware of any production C++ compilers that use any of these mechanisms. Maybe it's time to think about one?

Comment: Here is a paper from Stroustrup himself where he gives an example of a faster [dynamic cast](http://www.stroustrup.com/fast_dynamic_casting.pdf) implementation. However it's unclear to me how he hopes to extend it to support DLL (see *DYNAMICALLY LOADED CLASSES*), and most of the alternative schemes I have seen suffer from this issue: everything is easy without dynamically loaded code.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: So presumably a compiler could implement a faster mechanism, as long as it provided fallback to something that always works, and papered over the differences. Life doesn't get simpler for compiler writers, does it.